# Using StandardScaler on specific column in Pipeline and concatenate to original data

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline

I have a dataframe which has 4 numeric columns and I am trying to scale only one column using `StandardScaler` in a `Pipeline`. I used below code to scale and transform my column.

```
num_feat = ['Quantity']
num_trans = Pipeline([('scale', StandardScaler())])

preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(transformers = ['num', num_trans, num_feat])

pipe = Pipeline([('preproc', preprocessor),
                ('rf', RandomForestRegressor(random_state = 0))
                ])
```

After doing this I am splitting my data and training my model as below.

```
y = df1['target']
x = df1.drop(['target','ID'], axis = 1)
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size = 0.2)
pipe.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

This gives me error  `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)`. I understand this could be because of other 3 numeric columns in my dataframe. So how do I concatenate scaled data to my remaining dataframe and train my model on whole data. Or is there any better way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add a paranthesis when intialising the transformer.

```
preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(transformers = [('num', num_trans, num_feat)],remainder='passthrough')
```

Comment: There is small mistake in the intialisation of the column transformer. `preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(transformers = [('num', num_trans, num_feat)])` .  Can you please try this? The change is that you need to put paranthesis around the fields, `('num', num_trans, num_feat)`

Comment: Such a silly mistake of parenthesis that I couldn't notice. Thank you the model is training now.

Comment: Ok. Glad to know. Editing my answer to include paranthesis